# Use laravel livewire component without livewire counter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I go to the official website
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart
looking at Install Livewire, after Include the component, it said to add "counter" functionality and use the related functions in counter.blade.php, and then use <livewire:counter /> to introduce, but I hope the related functions are directly I use it in my blade as below, instead of using counter.blade and <livewire:counter /> , how can I do it?

mytest.blade.php

```
<div wire:poll.1000ms>Current time: {{ now() }}</div>

    @for ($i = 0; $i < count($DataSet); $i++)
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <div wire:poll.1000ms> {{$DataSet[$i]->real-time info}} </div>
        <div wire:poll.1000ms> {{$DataSet[$i]->real-time number}} </div>
        </div>
    @endfor
```

I tried to google how to introduce livewire into laravel route or try to put the relevant content of Counter.php into my controller, but it didn't solve it, hope someone can tell me how to work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [Inline Components](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#inline-components) you can't just add `Livewire` functionality to a non Livewire view, it doesn't work like that unfortunately. For your Livewire functionality to render and work correctly, you need to use either one of the `@livewire()` or `<livewire:>` directives for Laravel to recognise what you're trying to do.

You can alternatively use [Full-Page Components](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#page-components) which do not require you to add either of the directives to an existing Blade view as they render directly.

It is conventional and advisable to keep your `Component` and `Component` `view` names the same. However, if you want/require to use a different view you can change it in the `render()` function of your `Component`

```
class MyComponent extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        // Following convention ...
        // return view('livewire.my-component');

        // alternatively 
        return view('some-other-view');
    }
}
```

I would recommend against overriding the `view` you return with one of your non-Livewire views as arguably, a Livewire `Component` should be decoupled and by returning a view that mixes Livewire and non-Livewire functionality couples those two things together.